# Facebook Like Button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm having issues with the Facebook like button on my pages.  On some pages (not all), I get a red 'Error' notice next to the like button.  When clicking error it says that the "Page at ____ cannot be reached".

The URL Linter shows everything as fine with my pages.

Anything else I should check?

Using Javascript + XFBML, no iframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs if the page you're "Like"ing is not accessible from Facebook's servers. Are you testing this locally? Is it in a password-protected area? If either of these things are true, Facebook won't be able to find the page, and will assume that real users can't find it either.

Comment: The pages are live on the internet, on a public site.  I've confirmed I can access the page externally, and I think that using the URL Linter being able access it backs that up too.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Huh... looks like this is a known issue for pages that have not yet been "Like"d. It was reported over a month ago, and there seems to be no fix/workaround (though some of the examples are working for me.) http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10674 ... are you using the FeatureLoader.js script? If so, try removing it.

Comment: Specifically, check out this comment from a developer... there may be some solutions in there: http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10674#c188

Comment: Not using FeatureLoader, I'll check out that bug page - thanks